# Jump to different Times manually

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there a way to have embed youtube video and trigger to jump to manually positions programatically?

The user who is submitting a link to our video-gallery can also input some highlights (like 0:13, 5:25, 8:41) and it would be cool, if other users just click on the time-point and the video would jump to there.

Answer (score 0):

format:

```
(youtubeURL)#t=(no. of mins.)m(no. of secs.)s
```

example:

```
#t=2m35s will move to 2:36 of the video.
```

When embedding, just use the format.
example:

```
 <a href="<youtubeURL>#t=2m35s">Go to the solution</a>
```

Comment: well, that is working if the video is alrady loaded? thought thats just for a deeplink to a certain position

Comment: it will load but move directly to the time (won't show at the start).
you can test here: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCL06s-pGvU#t=2m45s`
link:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCL06s-pGvU#t=2m45s)

Comment: you didnt got my question right. i know how to jump to a position. i want to do this programatically with multiple positions on an event

Comment: you see that in comments of live-music videos. they just post when which song starts and you can jump their straight.

Comment: you mean create a <script> and a variable for the time to dynamically set the <iframe> src?

Comment: exactly that was my question :)

Comment: using jquery, you can add this to the button or link click event with the parameters:  

`function goToTime(url, min,sec){
var timeStart = url + "#t=" + min + "m" + sec + "s";
$("#youtubeframe").attr('src',timeStart);
}`

Comment: ill give that i try. didnt knew i can do that by just modifying the src tag